# $i(D) = 0$ provided $\deg D>2g-2$

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-surfaces

$\newcommand{\u}{\mathfrak{U}}$
**Definition**. For a divisor $\u$ on $M$, we set a $\Bbb C$-vector space
$$L(\u) = \{f\in\mathcal{K}(M);(f)\geq \u\},$$
where $\mathcal{K}(M)$ denotes a field of meromorphic functions on $M$. $$r(\u) =\dim_{\Bbb C}L(\u).$$
Similarly, we define a $\Bbb C$-vector space
$$\Omega(\u) = \{\omega;\omega\ \text{is a meromorphic differential with}\ (\omega)\geq\u\}.,$$
and
$$i(\u) = \dim\Omega(\u).$$

**Theorem (Riemann-Roch)**. *Let $M$ be a compact Riemann surface of genus $g$ and $\u$ an integral divisor on $M$. Then*
$$r(\u^{-1}) = \deg\u-g+1+i(\u).$$

> Let $D$ be a divisor on $M$ which is a compact Riemann surface of genus $g$. Then $i(D) = 0$ provided $\deg D>2g-2$.

This is a statement in Farkas & Kra Riemann surfaces without much explanation. Why this is true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take any meromorphic form $\alpha$ on $X$.  Let $K=(\alpha)$  (canonical divisor), Then $i(D)\cong r(D-K)$ by sending $\omega$ to $\omega/\alpha$. Then we can get another form of Riemann-Roch:
$$ r(-D)-r(D-K)=1-g+deg D
$$
Let $D=0$ and $D=K$, we can get $deg K=2g-2$. So if $\omega\in i(D)$ and $deg (D)\geq 2g-1$, then $(\omega)-(\alpha)\geq D-K$. Then
$$ deg\left(\frac{\omega}{\alpha}\right)\geq 1
$$
But deg $(f)$ should be $0$ by Residue Theorem. So $\omega=0$.

We actually proved that all meromorphic forms have the same degree $2g-2$.